# Ongoing notifications getting canceled upon clicking

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to create an ongoing notification using remoteviews. Problem is upon clicking, the notification gets canceled.

Comment: share your code please

Answer (score 1):

That's because you've set

```
notification.flag = Notification.auto_cancel
```

or

```
new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
```

Remove any of these code snippets then it will be ok.